# Send data from fragment to activity android C#

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, android-activity, xamarin

i'm new to xamarin android. i want to send data from fragment to MainActivity.
i searched google a lot almost all of them was in Java.

Comment: This link can be answer for you https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/create_a_fragment/

Comment: Make some static fields and methods in your activity or use its Bundle to put some extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Access the parent activity.
   Create a function called SetData(data) in your activity class.
   Your fragmnet have the "Activity" property, so cast to your activity type and then call the setData function with your data.

   ((ParentActivity)this.Activity).SetData(data);
2. Use the **SharedPreferences**
   Set (in fragment):

   ```
   ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
   ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
   editor.PutString("my_data", "some_data");
   editor.Apply();
   ```

   Get (in activity):

   ```
   ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (context);
   String myData = prefs.GetString ("my_data", "");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using Delegates:

Define delegates in your Fragment class

```
namespace Awesome.Android {
     public class AwesomeFragment : Fragment {

       public delegate void OnAwesomePress (int number);
       public event OnAwesomePress sendOnAwesomePressEvent;
     }
}
```

You can assign it when you create a Framgent

```
AwesomeFragment fragment = new AwesomeFragment ();
fragment.OnAwesomePress += OnAwesomePress;
```

After that, you implement `OnAwesomePress` in your activity

```
private void OnAwesomePress (int number) {

}
```

Now, when you call `sendOnAwesomePressEvent` in your Fragment, that event will be passed to Activity.

```
sendOnAwesomePressEvent (10);
```